# jquery colorbox form submit event not triggered

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, colorbox

I have a div with id="yearbookorder" and it is hidden. After a click event a colorbox show up with that yearbookorder ID DIV.

In that div, here is the code:

```
<form id="yearbook_order" name="yearbook_order" action="yearbook/order" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <input class="ordering" name="yb_email" value="" >
    <input type="submit" id="order" name="order" value="Send it!">
</form>
```

I have a jquery ajax code to submit, but the form submit event is not triggered:

```
$(function()
    {
        $("#yearbook_order").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dataString = $("#yearbook_order").serialize();   
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "yearbook/order",
            data: dataString,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) 
            {
                if (data.status == 'error')
                {
                    alert(data.message);
                    //$("#msg").html(data.message);
                }
                else
                {
                    //$("#msg").html(data.message);
                    alert(data.message);
                }
            }  
            });               
        });
    });
```

When I click the submit button, the form is not submitted. But why? When I call this form not in colorbox but on a blank page, it is working. It is a problem with the hidden yearbookorder DIV?

Comment: So the problem is the AJAX call is not working?

Comment: No, when I place an alert("successfull submit); line after preventdefault, it is not triggered also. AJAX call doesn't work either.

Comment: Your problem is elsewhere, what you have works just fine. Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4gJXc/2/

Comment: Yeah without colorbox it is working, but in colorbox frame doesn't.

Comment: Last time I saw something like this, the person had an older version of colorbox, and the solution was to get the latest. Past that, I'm afraid you'd need to start debugging it. Sorry cannot help more.

Comment: Check for errors in your console for some other JS error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You are binding submit to the form before it exists. Bind the event to the document, and pass the form selector to .on:

$(document).on("submit", "#yearbook_order", function(e){
    // make ajax request here
});
```

Comment: $(handler) is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){}). Also, .on() is deprecated. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: ok this is working, but downloaded the newest colorbox, I have used a really old one, it is working now with this code flawlessly! Thank you!

Comment: I thought I was clear. The code he had was already binding to the document.ready() event. It was functionally the same as yours but more correct since it wasn't using a deprecated call. Either way, he fixed it, so it doesn't matter if it is working.

Comment: @MikeC,thanx for the explanation